# Combination of test.each, act and render produces warning when running tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

The following Jest test

```
const { render } = require('react-dom');
const { act } = require('react-dom/test-utils');

...

function Foo(props) {
  const { bar } = props;
  return <h1>{bar}</h1>;
}

test.each([[1], [2]])('generates a warning', (actual) => {
  act(() => render(
    <Foo bar={actual} />, 
    container
  ));
});
```

... produces the following warning

```
Warning: The callback passed to act(...) function must return undefined, or a Promise. You returned null
```

Running tests without `each` doesn't produce the warning. Why is this warning being produced and how to solve it?

Comment: What does Foo actually render?

Comment: updated example with contents of Foo